# How do I clone Distinct XML structures without data in PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML document that looks like this:

```
<root>

  <node/>

  <node>
    <sub>more</sub>
  </node>

  <node>
    <sub>another</sub>
  </node>

  <node>value</node>

</root>
```

Here's my pseudo-code:

```
import xml.

create empty-xml.

foreach child of imported-xml-root-node,

    recursively clone node structure without data.

    if clone does not match one already in empty-xml,
        then add clone to empty-xml.
```

I'm trying to get a result that looks like this:

```
<root>

  <node/>

  <node>
    <sub/>
  </node>

</root>
```

**Note** that my piddly example data is only 3 nodes deep. In production, there will be an unknown number of descendants, so an acceptable answer needs to handle variable node depths.

---

## Failed Approaches

I have reviewed [The DOMNode class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) which has a [`cloneNode`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.clonenode.php) method with a recursive option that I would like to use, although it would take some extra work to purge the data. But while the class contains a [`hasChildNodes`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.haschildnodes.php) function which returns a boolean, I can't find a way to actually return the collection of children.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

$root_node = $doc->documentElement;

if ( $root_node->hasChildNodes() ) {

  // looking for something like this:
  // foreach ($root_node->children() as $child)
  //   $doppel = $child->cloneNode(true);

}
```

---

Secondly, I have tried my hand with the [The SimpleXMLElement class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) which does have an awesome [`children`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) method. Although it's lacking the recursive option, I built a simple function to surmount that. But the class is missing a clone/copyNode method, and my function is bloating into something nasty to compensate. Now I'm considering combining usage of the two classes so I've got access to both `SimpleXMLElement::children` and `DOMDocument::cloneNode`, but I can tell this is not going cleanly and surely this problem can be solved better.

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$indentation = 0;

function getNamesRecursive( $xml, &$indentation )
{
    $indentation++;
    foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
        for($i=0;$i<$indentation;$i++)
          echo "\t";
        echo $child->getName() . "\n";
        getNamesRecursive($child,$indentation);
    }
    $indentation--;
}

getNamesRecursive($sxe,$indentation);
```

Comment: Portable root node selection: `$doc->documentElement`

Comment: @rjdown oh awesome, thanks! I edited my question to strike that part. great to know!

Comment: [DOMNode::$childNodes](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes) is a property, not a method.

Comment: @ThW oh sweet, I think that might be my answer in shining armor, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well here's my stinky solution. [suggestions for improvements](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132128/cloning-distinct-xml-structures-without-data-in-php) or completely new better answers are still very welcome.

```
$xml = '
<root>
  <node/>
  <node>
    <sub>more</sub>
  </node>
  <node>
    <sub>another</sub>
  </node>
  <node>value</node>
</root>
';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);


// clone without data
$empty_xml = new DOMDocument();
$empty_xml->appendChild($empty_xml->importNode($doc->documentElement));
function clone_without_data(&$orig, &$clone, &$clonedoc){
  foreach ($orig->childNodes as $child){
    if(get_class($child) === "DOMElement")
      $new_node = $clone->appendChild($clonedoc->importNode($child));
    if($child->hasChildNodes())
      clone_without_data($child,$new_node,$clonedoc);
  }
}
clone_without_data($doc->documentElement, $empty_xml->documentElement, $empty_xml);


// remove all duplicates
$distinct_structure = new DOMDocument();
$distinct_structure->appendChild($distinct_structure->importNode($doc->documentElement));
foreach ($empty_xml->documentElement->childNodes as $child){
  $match = false;
  foreach ($distinct_structure->documentElement->childNodes as $i => $element){
    if ($distinct_structure->saveXML($element) === $empty_xml->saveXML($child)) {
      $match = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!$match)
    $distinct_structure->documentElement->appendChild($distinct_structure->importNode($child,true));
}
$distinct_structure->formatOutput = true;
echo $distinct_structure->saveXML();
```

Which results in this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <node/>
  <node>
    <sub/>
  </node>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files. And PHP maintains an XSLT 1.0 processor. You simply need to keep items of position 1 and copy only its elements not text.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file to use below in php)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>      
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Remove any nodes position greater than 2 -->
  <xsl:template match="*[position() &gt; 2]"/>   

  <!-- Copy only tags -->
  <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**PHP**

```
// LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->load('Input.xml');

$xslfile = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xslfile->load('Script.xsl');

// TRANSFORM XML with XSLT
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xslfile); 
$newXml = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

// ECHO OUTPUT STRING
echo $newXml;
# <root>
#   <node/>
#   <node>
#     <sub/>
#   </node>
# </root>

// NEW DOM OBJECT
$final = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$final->loadXML($newXml);
```

Comment: wow this looks amazingly simple. I can't wait to give it a test drive in the morning :) thank you! btw, how did you stumble across my question? I thought for sure it was buried by now.

Comment: I really love the elegance, so I've got quite a bit of learning ahead of me now for XSL :) However, it appears that `match="/*/*/*"` limits it to 3 nodes deep. Just using `*` only gives me root. I'm tinkering now with the section `Remove any nodes position greater than 2`. My actual use case will have an unknown number of node depths, hence my recursive strategy.

Comment: I'm confused by how the properties scale out. For instance, if I add a node with text inside one of the `sub` nodes, increase `position() &gt; 3`, and `match="/*/*/*/*"`, it works as expected *except* that only one of the nodes still has text in it.

Comment: Indeed, I love XSLT (not too many PHPers or Pythoners use it). I'm good but not the best and your task is beyond me. Consider asking same question in the XSLT section. For PHP you need an XSLT 1.0 version. The gurus there can you get a generalizeable solution! I know it will need to a recursive `<xsl:param>` to count node depths.